# Jenkins API Access Denied

Tags: php, jenkins

I'm trying to connect my WordPress website to my jobs Jenkins via the Jenkins API. Even if I saw a lot of posts and tried them I still don't manage to make my Jenkins API working.

So I have a Jenkins running in `http://localhost:9090` with the job `Test`.

I configured the HTTP proxy of Jenkins at `proxy:8080` with my username and password. When I validate the proxy in Jenkins, it's a success.

Jenkins tells me as well that my token was `never used`.

Now about my API, I have:

```
function getLastBuildStatus($url, $jobName, $username, $api_token){
    $password = 'xxxxx';
    $ch = initCurl($username, $api_token); //see function downside

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . '/job/' . $jobName . '/lastBuild/api/json');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'http://proxy:8080');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password); 

    $result = executeCurl($ch);
    $json = json_decode($result);
    var_dump ($result);
    if($json){
        return $json->result;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }

function initCurl($username, $api_token){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false ); 
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false ); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $api_token); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    return $ch;
}
```

With or without proxy I have an `Access Denied` error. Am I missing something?

## Edit 1

I've add in the `httpd.conf` rules for the Jenkins proxy reverse. Still the same error but probably something to look deeper..

```
ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:9090/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:9090/
ProxyRequests     Off
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
<Proxy http://localhost:9090/*>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

## Edit 2

OK! So I could make it work via command line. When I enter that command, I can access the data:

```
curl  -v --noproxy localhost, http://localhost:9090/job/Test/api/json --user username:token
```

I don't get why because when I put `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, false);` in my PHP file, I still get the `403 error`.

However, when I put `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '');`, I get a `Error:Failed to connect to localhost port 9090: Connection refused`

Comment: Try changing `$username . ":" . $password)` to `"$username:$password)"`

Comment: still the same error `Access Denied`

Comment: Is the `$api_token` correct?

Comment: Where is the `$password` var defined ?

Comment: `$password` is defined in the function, I edited the post, I forgot it. 
`$api_token` is the one I find in Jenkins so yes it must be correct. 
Thing is the entiere error is:  `Access Denied. Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect. Name of my cache administrator`. So it must be something related to the proxy, right ?